# iOS : Mistake with setFont

Tags: ios, label

I'm trying to use setFont on a label, but it seems it doesn't work on iOS > = 8.

I wrote :

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:12];
[self->myLabel setFont:font];
```

Any ideas ?

EDIT : The problem isn't on the font, but on the SIZE. The label stay on the "default" size wrote in the storyboard.

Comment: It's working with iOS 7, so I've the font.

Comment: Ahah I love it !  Apple delete Helvetica, its own font, to use the new for iOS 9 ? Seriously ? :(

Comment: It's not possible the font doesn't exist because I'm using it on the storyboard.. :/

Comment: (and nop, doesn't work too... so the problem is not here ?)

Comment: Nop... because I tried to update the text, and it works. (and like I said, it works on iOS 7, very strange :/)

Comment: I edited my post, the problem isn't the font, but the size.

Comment: I never said the font is nil... You're saying that. Sorry, I forgot to say that in my topic. (and it's logic, Apple will never delete its own font :))

Answer (score 0):

It's because there is no font family with name `@"HelveticaNeue-Light"` hence `size:12` will also not work

And also make sure `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` is disabled with

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO
```

You can get the available fonts in attribute inspector of Interface Builder

Comment: I can use HelveticaNeue-Light in storyboard, and not in the code ? No sense :/ (and it will be incredible if Apple do that with it's own font..)

Comment: make sure `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` is disabled

Comment: I edited my post, the problem isn't the font, but the size.